# Cross-contamination between AngularJS tests

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

We have a configuration file that we use in our AngularJS app. Because we need our configuration information during the build phase, we define it as a value. The configuration file contains information about where to find the assets for one of several Assessments, so we have a configurationService with an updateAssessment() function that looks in the configuration file at the various Assessments that are defined and then copies the properties from the specific Assessment into another value, assessmentSettings.

We have some situations where we want to read in some additional settings from an XML files, but when those settings are already provided as part of the configuration for that Assessment, we want to ignore them. I have a test that checks that this is done and it runs and passes.

However, massaging the project configuration value, then calling configurationService.updateAssessment(1) in that test causes 41 other tests *in different files* to fail. My understanding is that Angular should be torn down and brought back up for each test and should certainly not cross-contaminate across different files. Is there something different about values that would cause this to happen?

Note that the project itself seems to load and run fine. I haven't provided code examples because it would be a fair amount of code and I don't think it would be that enlightening. Angular 1.3.

Comment: I guess that some code won't hurt. It isn't too obvious what's wrong in your case.

Comment: So, do you restart angular for each test? I guess it is the issue, because `configurationService` seems to preserve configuration values between different specs.

Comment: My understanding is that the testing framework (karma/jasmine) *should* restart angular for each test. It doesn't appear to be doing so, which is the heart of the question.

Comment: Note that I really hate when people vote to close a question because they, personally, don't understand the question. I'm hoping to attract people who understand how karma and jasmine bootstrap angularjs between tests. IMO no testing framework should allow any cross-contamination even between specific tests, much less tests in other files. I get that not everyone understands testing frameworks, but just because you don't doesn't mean no one out there will find this question clear and specific.

Comment: If you aren't mocking your service, you should be. Cross contamination could be coming from there.

Comment: How? The other tests don't call that method. So if AngularJS is restarted for each test as it should be, there should be no way that calling it in one test affects others.